# jQuery crawler big object / $.each / Ajax IN then Ajax OU

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, each

I'm building a crawler for fun in jQuery... But I got a problem for the final step, which is get some ajax content, explore it, then save the result with ajax.

Here is an example of the object:

```
finalResult = [];

links = {
    categorie1:{
        categorie2:{
            categorie3:{
                products:{
                    link1,...,linkN
                    //get the content url with ajax
                        ajaxCall(link);
                    //load the content into an hidden div
                        ajaxSuccess(data);
                    //parse the content with selectors
                        myProduct = data.find(selectors).do();
                    //put all the infos into an object
                        finalResult.push(myProduct);
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

So as you guess, I'm going to the links with each inside each inside each etc...There is 5500 links so a lot.

Then, when my 5500 loops are done, I want to send the object finalResult to a php page with ajax to record all of these products.

Everything work fine until i reach more than 3500 products, then my browser just crash or become really slow and doesn't answer.

So I'd like to save the finalProducts every 50 iterations then do the 50 following etc... etc.. In this way I think it will easier to manipulate much smaller object.

But I don't see how to do that... Any idea ?

Thanks guys,

Comment: Well, a browser does have a memory limit… Querying 5500 pages might just be too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some differnet approach to solve this problem.

As, you have your JSON. 
Just stringify the whole JSON using JSON.stringify().

Then split on the basis of link.
Concat all link in a single variable.
Do this for whole Strigified data.
Finally make your AJAX request.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should make another object with all the links, then stringily this object, cut the string and then works on the links... Could work but is there any way to split an object directly ?

Comment: If you can achive your goal with string formation, then please go with this approach. Becoz, this is performance wise lot better that ittration over object properties.

Comment: Well i change a bit my approach. Now I'm put all links in a simple array, then I splice this array in block 50 blocks of hundreds links and I add a timeout of a few seconds before each block. I'm at 60% of the 5k links now and seems good, we'll see in an hour :) Thanks for your support anyway

Comment: It seems great. :)
But still I am unaware how you are doing, and why its taking too long.